# searchAndScreenPop() search only against phone fields

Tags: search, opencti, cti

The function [searchAndScreenPop()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_cti/Content/sforce_api_cti_searchandscreenpop.htm) of the OpenCti Api searches for a given string in all records specified in the SoftPhone layout and returns the search results as a Json string.

Unfortunately, the search is executed on every field of the specified object types on a 'contains' principle (in earlier versions of the api, the search was implemented on a 'starts with' principle). I would expect the function to search only 'Phone Fields' or to provide the possibility to specify what fields are searched.

Is anyone aware of that behavior? Is there a possibility to pass a SOQL search query or is there any other way to control this search?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create your own SOSL query (or queries) in an Apex class and call runApex() to run your custom query.  Then you can process the results and call screenPop() to pop to the record of interest.

Comment: That's a possible solution. But unfortunately I was unable to access the softphone layout content in a apex class. To my knowledge this is only accessible on behalf of the OpenCTI api. Furthermore it is not my preferred solution to rebuild the searchAndScreenPop functionality on my own.